# checkbox effect only one row in table

Tags: javascript

I am trying that when i click on checkbox hidden field of "present" id become visible  if i uncheck the checkbox then hidden field of "absent" id become visible.But when i click on checkbox only first row of table is affected while other rows didn't affect when checkbox is checked or unchecked. Following is the html code

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
 <tr>
    <td><strong> Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Phone</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Cnic</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Attendence</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Status</strong></td>
  </tr> 
 <?php foreach($user as $USER){?>
  <form method="post" action="">
 <tr>
    <td>
      <input  type="text" name="name" value="<?=$USER->name;?>" readonly>
      <input type="hidden" name="u_id" value="<?=$USER->u_id;?>">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="<?=$USER->email;?>" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?=$USER->phone;?>" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="cnic" value="<?=$USER->cnic;?>" readonly>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center">
      <input type="checkbox"name="checkbox"id="checkbox" onclick="visibility()">
    </td>
    <td>
      <span style="visibility: hidden; color: green;"><input type="text" name="att" value="Present" id="present"></span>
      <span style="visibility: hidden; color: red;"><input type="text" name="att" value="Absent" id="absent"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>     
    <?php }?>  
 </form>
</table>
```

And following is the JavaScript code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function visibility() {
        if (document.getElementById("checkbox") . checked == true){
          document.getElementById("present").style.visibility ="visible";
          document.getElementById("absent").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }else{
          document.getElementById("absent").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("present").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }     
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: Use class to select element you want to check instead of ID i.e document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox') and you should be fine

Comment: `id` attribute should be unique to distinguish checkboxes

Comment: By using class name no row is affecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following method:

- While rendering your form, also send user id as parameter to `visibility` method.

  ```
  onclick="visibility(<?=$USER->u_id;?>)"
  ```
- Set id of absent & present fields by appending user id to the id attribute.

  ```
  <span style="visibility: hidden; color: green;"><input type="text" name="att" value="Present" id="present<?=$USER->u_id;?>"></span>
  <span style="visibility: hidden; color: red;"><input type="text" name="att" value="Absent" id="absent<?=$USER->u_id;?>"></span>
  ```
- Similarly set id of checkbox.

  ```
  <input type="checkbox"name="checkbox"id="checkbox<?=$USER->u_id;?>" onclick="visibility(<?=$USER->u_id;?>)">
  ```
- Use the user id sent as parameter to `visibility` method to identify the id of element.

  ```
  function visibility(id) {
    if (document.getElementById("checkbox"+id) . checked == true){
      document.getElementById("present"+id).style.visibility ="visible";
      document.getElementById("absent"+id).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("absent"+id).style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementById("present"+id).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }     
  }
  ```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      function visibility(id) {
        if (document.getElementById("checkbox"+id) . checked == true){
          document.getElementById("present"+id).style.visibility ="visible";
          document.getElementById("absent"+id).style.visibility = "hidden";
        }else{
          document.getElementById("absent"+id).style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("present"+id).style.visibility = "hidden";
        }     
      }
  </script>
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
 <tr>
    <td><strong> Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Phone</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Cnic</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Attendence</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Status</strong></td>
  </tr> 
 <?php foreach($user as $USER){?>
  <form method="post" action="">
 <tr>
    <td>
      <input  type="text" name="name" value="<?=$USER->name;?>" readonly>
      <input type="hidden" name="u_id" value="<?=$USER->u_id;?>">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="<?=$USER->email;?>" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?=$USER->phone;?>" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="cnic" value="<?=$USER->cnic;?>" readonly>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center">
      <input type="checkbox"name="checkbox"id="checkbox<?=$USER->u_id;?>" onclick="visibility(<?=$USER->u_id;?>)">
    </td>
    <td>
      <span style="visibility: hidden; color: green;"><input type="text" name="att" value="Present" id="present<?=$USER->u_id;?>"></span>
      <span style="visibility: hidden; color: red;"><input type="text" name="att" value="Absent" id="absent<?=$USER->u_id;?>"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>     
    <?php }?>  
 </form>
</table>
```

Comment: sir i use this code now every checkbox work but still there is a problem if first row checkbox is checked status become present and all other row check box show present status even if checkbox is unchecked status remain present. other checkbox result is depending on first row's checkbox if first row's checkbox is checked all other check boxes show present status if it is not checked all other check boxes show absent status

Comment: thank you sir for your help, now code is working. Actually i was not appending u_id with checkbox id that's why i was facing error. Once again thanks for your help sir

Comment: @sameedulhassan glad to know it helped....please do accept & upvote answers so that others can also find it helpful

Comment: sorry sir my reputation is less then 15 that's why my vote is not showing publicly.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this

```
 <span style="visibility: hidden; color: green;"><input type="text" name="att" value="Present" class="present"></span>
      <span style="visibility: hidden; color: red;"><input type="text" name="att" value="Absent" class="absent"></span>


<script type="text/javascript">
      function visibility() {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox") . checked == true){
          document.getElementsByClassName("present").style.visibility ="visible";
          document.getElementsByClassName("absent").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }else{
          document.getElementsByClassName("absent").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementsByClassName("present").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }     
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: sir by using this method if one checkbox is checked status of all row will be affect. i want only one row affect by checking its corresponding checkbox

Answer (score 0):

id must be unique.

add just parameter in your function e.g
 onclick="visibility(1)" --for first row and pass 2 insted of 1 and so on also do this for your id id="present_1" and id="absent_1" and so on and the js function is as below

```
  function visibility(no) {
    if (document.getElementById("checkbox") . checked == true){
      document.getElementById("present_"+no).style.visibility ="visible";
      document.getElementById("absent_"+no).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("absent_"+no).style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementById("present_"+no).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }     
  }
```

Hope its work